# Colocar em array strings de acordo com uma expressão regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu gostaria de fazer um array contendo strings nesse formato:

```
[Texto com acento espaço e números 99]
```

Exemplo, caso eu tenha essa string:

```
var texto = "Eu quero comprar [qtdOvos] e [qtdFrutas] somando o total de [totalCompras]";
```

Preciso montar o seguinte array:

```
var arrayStrings = ["[qtdOvos]", "[qtdFrutas]", "[totalCompras]";
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso através de expressão regular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possivel. Podes usar: `.match(/(\[\w+\])/g)`.

Neste caso tens de "escapar" as `[` pois são reservadas em Regex. Crias um grupo de captura com `()`, usas `\w+` para dizer que é uma letra ou numero e `g` para dizer que é recorrente.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3sc6vvoj/

Se quiseres "apanhar" tudo o que estiver dentro de `[]` de maneira mais abrangente podes usar `/(\[.*?\])/g`.

Comment: E se eu precisar de uma palavra com acento?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo  tudo o que estiver dentro de `[]` queres "apanhar" certo? nesse caso podes ter `/(\[.*?\])/g`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var texto = "Eu quero comprar [qtdOvos] e [qtdFrutas] somando o total de [totalCompras]";
var arrayStrings = texto.match(/\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\]/gi);
```

`arrayStrings` vai conter exatamente o que você quer:

```
["[qtdOvos]", "[qtdFrutas]", "[totalCompras]"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra expressão que pode ser utilizada é `/\[(?:.*?)\]/` que vai corresponder a tudo que estiver entre *`[`* e *`]`*.

```
var texto = "Eu quero comprar [qtdOvós] e [qtdFrutâs] somando o total de [total Comprãs]";    
var array = texto.match(/\[(?:.*?)\]/g);

// [qtdOvós],[qtdFrutâs],[total Comprãs]
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wp0whew/)</kbd>